# Keeping a variable created by substr

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with several variables, one of which is *truc*. I want to create a new variable that is only the two first characters of the variable *truc*, let us call it *truc2*.

I know how to create it

```
data want ;
    set have;
    truc2=substr(truc,1,2);
run;
```

My problem is that if I only do that, my new variable *truc2* is not kept in my want table.
I can add a keep instruction `want(keep=var2)`, but then I have to add all the variables that I want to keep too, which is very tedious.
Moreover if I add a variable by, for instance,

```
truc3=truc
```

it is automatically kept.

So why is it not the case with a new variable created by substr()? And how can I keep it without typing all other variables?

Comment: Is truc a character variable in the "have" dataset?  A numeric truc would result in truc2 variable that is always missing.

Comment: It is a character variable yes. And when I precise to keep it ( data want(keep=truc2) it gives the expected variable.

Comment: Then there's something else going on in your real-world problem.  Your example program works fine.

Comment: Stupid question, I just realized the variable had been created in a previous step, that is why the number of variables did not change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SQL instead?

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE want as
  SELECT *,
  substr(truc,1,2) as truc2
  FROM HAVE;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Not that I am opposed to that solution, but 1) is it better in some definitions of better ? 2) I would nevertheless be happy to understand why I have to add the keep option in a data step.

Comment: I was confused as to why your original solution didn't work. This solution would have at least told you that you already had a variable called `truc2` on submission.

Comment: And indeed it has. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
data want (drop=trunc2);
    set have;
    truc2=substr(truc,1,2);
run;
```